# PHPMailer - Sending to multiple address but unique content

Tags: php, email

I am building a quote system, the quote system sends out the quote to multiple people with a personalised message via email. I am using the following code to do so:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->AddReplyTo("myAddress@domain.com", "Company"); 
$mail->SetFrom('quotes@company.com', 'COMPANY');

// Set each of the recipients 

$users = $quote->GetClients();

foreach($users as $user)
{
    $mail->AddAddress($user["Email"], $user["Name"]);
}

$mail->Subject = "Hello" . $users[0]["Name"]; 

$body = "This is your personal Email";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->Send();
```

The problem being is that, when I send this email, it sends to all the recipients that it should, but it includes all of the recipients names. Whereas, I just want to display for that particular person. I.e. If I get an email, it would be: "Hello Phorce, This is your Personal Email" but instead I get "Hello {user1} {user2} {user3}" and this is not what I want.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do using PHPMailer?